# Passing value of javascript variable to PHP variable using AJAX is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm new in programming. Sorry if my codes are messy. I want to ask about passing value from JS variable to PHP variable.

I have 2 files.

First is **ajaxvariable4.php** that contains HTML and jQuery AJAX.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <select name="target" id="target">
                <option value="Ferrari">Car</option>
                <option value="Wimcycle">Bicycle</option>
            </select>
            <script>
                        $( "#target" ).change(function() {
                        var vehicle=$('#target option:selected').val();

                            $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            data: { 'vehicle': vehicle },
                            url: "passingajax.php",
                            success: function(json) {
                                $("#tb").val(vehicle);
                                }
                            });
                        });
            </script>
            <input type="text" id="tb">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Second is **passingajax.php** that contains PHP variable to save value from JS variable.

```
 <?php 
if( isset($_POST['vehicle']) )
{
     $vehicle= $_POST['vehicle'];
     echo $vehicle;
}else{
    echo "Data doesn't exist";
}
?>
```

When I executed **ajaxvariable4.php** , the ajax call was success and the column with **id=tb** filled with value that selected in option. But when I executed **passingajax.php** the output was **Data doesn't exist**. So I assume that **variable vehicle** in **passingajax.php** didn't receive value from JS variable.

My question is if the ajax call was success, why the **variable vehicle** in **passingajax.php** didn't receive value from JS variable ?

Comment: Try `$('#tb').val(json);`.

Comment: Check the request sent in your "Network tab" in the browser developper

Comment: @vivek_23 where i put `$('#tb').val(json);` to save value from AJAX to variable `$vehicle` in **passingajax.php** ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Is it use another app to check the request ?

Comment: Use the 'F12'  key

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki i already check it and the request is success and the response also true

Comment: @YanAditiyaNugraha Try that in your success function of your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code:

```
$('#target').change(function () { 
    var vehicle = $("#target >option:selected").val(); 
}
```

Form:

```
 <select name="target" id="target" onChange="test(this.value)">
            <option value="Ferrari">Car</option>
            <option value="Wimcycle">Bicycle</option>
 </select>
```

JQuery:

```
function test(t){
  console.log(t.value);
}
```

Comment: variable `$vehicle` in **passingajax.php** was not getting the value in data AJAX

Comment: @Cristal you can't post a question as an answer. Comment instead.

Comment: @Cristal i try `$('#target').change(function () { 
    var vehicle = $("#target >option:selected").val(); 
}` and it's still not pass value to variable `$vehicle`.

Comment: In this case, you can try adding onChange method. I have updated my answer above